# rxjs forkJoin does not call subscribe

Tags: rxjs

I have a set of RxJs Observable that uses **forkJoin**.  The issue I have is that the **forkJoin** makes the calls but **subscribe** does not get calls.

However, if I use **zip** it works.

I have [created an example in StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-m9qmth). Is this a bug or am I doing it all wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

forkJoin only runs once all inner observables have completed. In your example, the inner observables never complete. zip runs once everytime all observables fire in order. If you want something to run anytime any observable fires, use combineLatest